# Software to draw figures in the display

Tags: display, drawing, real-time

I just want to ask if someone knows some software to draw in real time shapes on screen, like a rectangle.

This is very util for me for example when Copying stuff, or adapting stuff from a place that contains similar code. A pretty basic example is when you are copying or adapting text/code in the same display, but there are a lot of text and you or have a way to highlight it, but mostly programs doesn't contain that functionality.

Help would be appreciated! THANKS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help. The only thing is that the program is an overlay so if you move your window or scroll, the highlighted stuff won't move with the window. Didn't see that it specifically did a rectangle but you can definitely highlight text.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/epic-pen-highlight-draw-anywhere-over-desktop-open-windows/

Not too sure if that's what you were looking for but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Yeh, is a starting point, I was really looking for the rectangle but this does the job. Thanks